# How to import liblas module in Python?

Tags: python, ubuntu, import, lidar, liblas

I am using liblas for python to read .las file. When I enter:

```
from liblas import file
```

It gives me:

> No module named liblas.

I already set up las library path in system, `lasinfo` is working fine. Can anyone tell me how to import las library in Python? I am using Ubuntu by the way.

Comment: Have you installed [this Python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/libLAS) ?

Comment: Actually I installed libLas from [this](http://www.liblas.org/). What are the differences?

Comment: @Saddy_Grade: If you install python packages using pip/easy_install, it should also install the required dependencies with it.

Comment: You have the C/C++ LibLas libraries. Now you also need their python bindings. If your liblas library is installed fine, download the Python package (link that I gave) and install it using pip/easy_install command.

Comment: @RedBaron: I followed your instruction, and run test script. it can not found liblas_c.so shared object. How do I configure the path?

Comment: Looks like the basic liblas package (C/C++ one) wasn't installed correctly. Sorry I can't help you with that because I have no idea about the said software.

Comment: I reinstall it and it works! thanks for you help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the liblas is not properly installed or you configured the path incorrectly. Try installing the package **liblas** using pip or easy_install.

```
$ easy_install liblas OR $ pip install liblas
```

Comment: Sorry, I am new to python. Yes, I am trying to read and display its content. however, when I run the python script, it gave me **ImportError: No module named liblas**

Comment: @Saddy_Grade: how did you installed the liblas module? Did you use pip or easy_install for it?

Comment: I use cmake to install liblas

Comment: I got this **error: Couldn't find a setup script in /tmp/easy_install-OM1U99/libLAS-1.6.0.win32.zip** . Why is it searching liblas and find the best match is **libLAS 1.6.0.win32**. my system is linux

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

After installing the module liblas, I tried to import it but it failed everytime.

**What you can do:**

1. Go to the folder which contains your download liblas folder (for me: /Users/blablabla/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/libLAS-1.6.0-py2.7.egg). This folder contains 2 folders: EGG-INFO and liblas.
2. Copy-paste liblas (the folder) into the parent folder (site-packages).

Now go to Python, and import liblas. It should work.